# Force div contents to be on one line

Tags: html, css

I looked on here for solutions but when I tried it, it didnt work. I want the alphabet to be on a single line. Please ignore my use of inline elements:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; whitespace: nowrap;">
A 
B 
C 
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
</div>
```

How do I get all the letters on one line?

EDIT: This is the site: http://goo.gl/tef6u

Comment: What do you mean by *didn't work*? Tried with Chrome and it looks fine..

Comment: @RavindraBagale OP does NOT want line breaks..

Comment: Well, they appear on individual lines and im in chrome too

Comment: Really? Can you confirm that on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDYqg/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your site you have `whitespace` it's meant to be `white-space`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/RUe6x/

Also, between every single letter you have a `<br>` line break, the only way to counter that is to either remove them or add

```
br
{
    display: none;
}
```

to your CSS if you can't change the HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/RUe6x/1/

Answer (score 0):

On the site you're referring to, there's a `<br/>` after every letter. `<br/>` means 'break' and is solely for jumping to the next line. So all you gotta do is remove those tags and you'll do fine.
P.s. don't use tags if you don't know what they're for ;)

Answer (score -1):

Please Check following link ,

here all alphabets are on single horizontal lines with `width: 100%;`
http://jsfiddle.net/QN68Q/5/

for setting alphabets on one vertical lines you can got following link setting `width: 1%;`
http://jsfiddle.net/QN68Q/4/

Comment: please can you explain what exactly u want? Because I used code given by you itys displaying all alphabets on one line..

Comment: You misunderstood the OP when he said all on one line, this usually means one horizontal line. You have it all on one vetical line which is what he has anyway. There's even a diagram displaying what he has in the question.